# How to say "fact" in Japanese

Tags: translation

How would you translate "10 facts about Japan"?

I looked it up but there seem to be many translations for "fact", and I'm not sure if I should use ないじつ, じこう or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the severity of what you are trying to convey, there are different options.

If it's very objective matter -- possibly a strong or stern tone like in a news report or something -- I think `事実` is probably best.  This would best suit a scenario like:

> 10 facts about Japan
>
> 1. The capital is Tokyo
> 2. The literacy rate is over 95%
> 3. ...

However, if it's something more casual -- for example, personal observations that you're writing in a blog -- you might want to use `[豆知識]{まめ・ち・しき}`.  This translates more along the lines of "trivia", "fun facts", or "tidbits".

Comment: "10 (hard/actual) facts about Japan" does not sound like a very likely title: "10 things you did not know about Japan", yes, "Ten little known facts about Japan", yes, but this (ie ""... "") is not easy to translate meaniningfully.

Comment: @Tim:  I did not mean to imply that "(hard/actual)" was part of the title; simply giving some characterization to the type of facts I was trying to convey.

Comment: 10の事実(jijitsu) is the best, I think. And more colloquial expression is 10の事(koto).